# jwt middleware in laravel vue

Tags: laravel, jwt, vuejs3

Jwt token is not found

i create middleware JWT.php and code here

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth;

class JWT
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next): Response
    {
        JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

when i use this

```
public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('JWT');
    }
```

it show token is not found

i use this

```
 'JWT' => \App\Http\Middleware\JWT::class,
```

in kernel.php in  protected $middlewareAliases = [

and i define api route

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'api'], function () {
    Route::apiResource('/employee', EmployeeController::class); 
    Route::apiResource('/supplier', SupplierController::class);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to register it in `Kernel.php`.

```php
protected $middlewareAliases = [
    'JWT' => \App\Http\Middleware\JWT::class,
];
```

and to get the token, you need `api` middleware as stated in the [documentation](https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/quick-start/)

```php
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    .....
 
    'api' => [
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class.':api',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\JWT::class
    ],
];
```

Comment: protected $middlewareGroups = [
    .....
 
    'api' => [
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class.':api',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\JWT::class
    ],
];

when I use this it doesn't show any data on the route and I can not log in